# Upload an image and refresh div with new image

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code

```
<div id=form>
    <div id=viewimage>
        <img src="placeholder.png">
    </div>
    <div id=upload>
        <form action="upload.php" method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type=file name=image>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the image to be uploaded and then the #viewimage div to be refreshed with the submitted picture. When the form submits, the upload.php will return a file name of the uploaded file. I think this is an ajax question, but im a complete noob when it comes to ajax/javascript, so i dont have the slightest idea how to proceed.

Comment: So, as neither uploading an image nor reloading a div via ajax is particulary rocket science, what have you tried so far?

Comment: No idea how to reload a div with ajax after an image upload. I'm not sure if i need to put in a delay to allow for the upload, or what. There are particulars at work and since javascript/ajax isn't my area of expertise I'm consulting the community at large for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do do it in ajax, you should put your form inside an iframe, so when you upload the image, only a small part of the page (the form) is sent to your server.

After that, you can use upload.php response to get the name and path of uploaded image, and then you can just change the src of the img tag.